# laravel elequent - eager loading - load using condition from previous table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to use the relationship as its shown in the code:

```
$lesson = Lesson::with(['teacher.teacherLessons' => function($teacherLesson){
    $teacherLesson->whereHas('category.courses', function($course){ 
        $course->where('id', DB::raw('`lessons`.`course_id`'));
    });
}]);
```

i want to use the same id that was loaded by the main query raw, instead to use `DB::raw`,
how to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `whereColumn`/`orWhereColumn` method are there for just such a scenario.

> The `whereColumn` method may be used to verify that two columns are equal:

```php
$course->whereColumn('id', 'lessons.course_id');
```